# Set-up and Auto-Populate of Private Client Pages

Tags: wordpress, client, private

I'm a coding newbie and been tasked by my wife with setting up a website for her to sell a customisable online streaming product. I'm looking for some advice on private client pages - I've been searching online for about 3 days now and I can't find exactly what I'm looking for, so I'm turning to you guys and hopefully you can advise!

I'm going to set up a website with various payment options that relate to different hierarchies of membership. I want to have clients purchase a membership, and based on this membership, they will have access to a specific page. This page will be standard, but tailored to their membership. What is the best way to approach this? Is there a plug-in within Wordpress that will do this? Private Client Page, Client Portal, etc don't seem to offer this exact requirement.

In addition, I then need a further page which I can set up to action the customised 'order form' that they fill out above.

Thanks, I hope this was enough information.

Comment: Are you sure you want to program such stuff on your own? Why not use any existing e-commerce software for that?

Comment: Hi Nico, I'm keen to do this the easiest way possible! Would something like Shopify offer me this option?

Comment: Just try it :) You'll never know otherwise